# My label tag is causing my input box not to be clickable everywhere. How can I fixed that?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The input box don't seem to respond when I'm clicking along the same line as my label found in my input boxes. I used chrome to inspect it and it seems like my label stretches across my input which is blocking me from clicking it. I can't seem to figure out a work around.If I can somehow make my label tag have like a transparent property where I can click through it, if that make any sense.

```
body {
    background-color: #e0ece4;
}

.row .col {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.rotate {
    animation: rotation infinite 8s linear;
    width: 81px;
    height: 91px;
    display: block;
    margin: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.input-field label {
    text-indent: 5px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: #66bfbf;
}

input#first_name.validate {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
}
input#first_name.validate:focus {
    border: 3px solid green;
    
}
input#last_name.validate {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
input#last_name.validate:focus {
    border: 3px solid green;
    
}
input#phone_number.validate {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
input#phone_number.validate:focus {
    border: 3px solid green;
    
}
input#password.validate {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
input#password.validate:focus {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import '../CSS/index.css'


const SignUpForm = () => {
    return (
        <div className='row'>
            <form className='col s12'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='input-field col s6'>
                        <input id='first_name' type='text' className='validate' />
                        <label forhtml="first_name">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='input-field col s6'>
                        <input  id='last_name' type='text' className='validate'/>
                        <label forhtml="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='input-field col s6'>
                        <input id='phone_number' type='text' className='validate'/>
                        <label forhtml="phone_number">Phone Number</label>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='input-field col s6'>
                        <input id='password' type='password' className='validate'/>
                        <label forhtml="password">Password</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    )

}

export default SignUpForm
```

Comment: How does this belong to `material-ui`?

Comment: I'm using it on my front-end

Comment: You are using `forhtml` instead of `htmlFor`.

Comment: That's it, thx m8